# How to rount a number to tenth inside an 'int' function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, int, rounding

Here is my `convert_seconds` function:

```
def convert_seconds(x):
    hour = int(round(x / 3600))
    minute = int(round(x / 60 - hour * 60))
    second = int(round(x - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60), 1))
    return str(hour) + ' hours, ' + str(minute) + ' minutes, ' + str(second) +' seconds'
```

When i run my function:

```
>>>print convert_seconds(7261.7)
2 hours, 1 minute, 1 seconds
```

it print out "1 second" instead of "1.7 second"

Why is that?
How can I fix that?

NOTE: Output I need is:

```
>>>print convert_seconds(7261.7)
2 hours, 1 minute, 1.7 seconds
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is that?

Because you explicitly turn the result into an integer, removing anything beyond the decimal point:

```
second = int(round(x - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60), 1))
```

> How can I fix that?

Don't turn the `seconds` result into an integer:

```
second = round(x - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60), 1)
```

You should not round the `hour` and `minute` calculations; you should be flooring the results instead; `int()` by itself does that for you. Drop the `round()` calls for those two values. The `//` floor division operator would give you the same result as calling `int()` on the division result, removing the need to round or floor explicitly.

You can use formatting operations to then only show the values as decimals:

```
>>> def convert_seconds(x):
...     hour = x // 3600
...     minute = x // 60 - hour * 60
...     second = x - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60)
...     return '{:.0f} hours, {:.0f} minutes, {:.1f} seconds'.format(hour, minute, second)
... 
>>> convert_seconds(7261.7)
'2 hours, 1 minutes, 1.7 seconds'
```

To round a floating point value to 1 decimal but *drop* the `.0` if that is what it was rounded to, you'll need to explicitly string off the `.0`:

```
>>> def convert_seconds(x):
...     hour = x // 3600
...     minute = x // 60 - hour * 60
...     second = x - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60)
...     second_formatted = format(second, '.1f').rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
...     return '{:.0f} hours, {:.0f} minutes, {} seconds'.format(hour, minute, second_formatted)
... 
>>> convert_seconds(7261.7)
'2 hours, 1 minutes, 1.7 seconds'
>>> convert_seconds(7261)
'2 hours, 1 minutes, 1 seconds'
```

The expression `format(second, '.1f').rstrip('0').rstrip('.')` formats the `seconds` value but removes any `.0` by first stripping `0` followed by stripping the remaining `.`.

Instead of division and subtraction, you may want to use the [`divmod()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
def convert_seconds(x):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(x, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    second_formatted = format(seconds, '.1f').rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
    return '{:.0f} hours, {:.0f} minutes, {} seconds'.format(hours, minutes, second_formatted)
```

The `divmod()` function returns the result of the quotient *and* the remainder; `divmod(x, 60)` returns the number of minutes (number of times 60 fits in `x`), and the remainder seconds. Apply the same function again on the number of minutes, and you get hours and a minutes remainder.

Comment: yes but what about "convert_seconds(7325)", then seconds will be 5.0 instead of 5

Comment: i don't want it to be float (5.0) but i want it to be round too (1.666666 ~ 1.7, not 2). how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have other problems here too ;-)  For example,

```
>>> print convert_seconds(3500.0)
1 hours, -2 minutes, 20 seconds
```

In general, you're often rounding when you **should** be truncating.  This is easier to do working with integers, so the following separates the argument into integer and fractional parts, does most work with integers, and puts the fractional part back at the end (but only if needed - if it's not 0.0):

```
def convert_seconds(x):
    from math import modf
    frac, whole = modf(x)
    hours, leftover = divmod(int(whole), 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(leftover, 60)
    if frac:
        seconds += frac  # change to float to get fraction
    return "{} hours, {} minutes, {} seconds".format(
        hours, minutes, seconds)

for case in 3500.0, 7261.7, 7325:
    print case, "->", convert_seconds(case)
```

That prints:

```
3500.0 -> 0 hours, 58 minutes, 20 seconds
7261.7 -> 2 hours, 1 minutes, 1.7 seconds
7325 -> 2 hours, 2 minutes, 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

When you turn a float type into an int type, it will *discard* all decimal values and gives you the barebones integer underneath it all.

Try this:

```
def convert_seconds(x):
    hour = int(round(x / 3600))
    minute = int(round(x / 60 - hour * 60))
    second = float(round(x - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60), 1))
    return str(hour) + ' hours, ' + str(minute) + ' minutes, ' + str(second) +' seconds'

print(convert_seconds(7261.7))
```

You added a comment underneath where you asked, "yes but what about "convert_seconds(7325)", then seconds will be 5.0 instead of 5 "

You can do something like that to fix this problem. After doing the assignment to second:

```
second = float(round(x - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60), 1))
```

Do this:

```
second == int(second) if second == int(second) else second
```

"i don't want it to be float (5.0) but i want it to be round to (1.666666 ~ 1.7, not 2). how can i do that?"

You already do that! Your second argument to `round` is 1 which automatically rounds it off to one decimal place. Try doing `convert_seconds(7261.6666)` and this code will work.

Comment: Or you could use `{:g}`.